# Numerical instable integrals

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

I tried to calculate the value of the integral

I(n) := $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x^n+x^2+1}$ particularly for even and very large n,
(for example n=1000) with PARI and wolfram alpha. The results did not coincide,
so the calculation seems to be numerically unstable. Here are my questions :

1) Is there a general formula for calculating I(n) ?

2) How can the calculation be made numerically stable ?

3) Is it true that $\lim_{n->\infty}  I(n)$  = $\frac{\pi}{4}$ 
   and if yes, how can it be proven ?

I tried to use the identity

$\frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{x^n}{(x^2+1)(x^n+x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1}$ ,

but the calculation seems to keep numerically unstable.

Comment: Can be more explicit about the discrepancies? I tried the same thing in Mathematica and found no problems with the calculations.

Comment: Using a quick program I wrote in Mathematica I get your calculation for the $n=1000$ case as $0.78574508425400897722$. So if you want very good accuracy, I probably would not be using WolframAplha.

Comment: Also, I don't have the time to work through it now. However, if this question remains unanswered tonight I will come back to it and try it. This integral seems perfect for calculation using residues. Just create the standard loop along the real axis and then loop back to the origin to close it. You can calculate the residue for the general case $n$ then let $n\to \infty$. It does indeed seem numerically like $\lim_{n \to \infty} I(n)=\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: I found a proof for the limit using simple majorants.

Comment: Are you going to post it, or was it too long to fit into the margins?

Comment: Ok. There is the proof : 1) $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^n+x^2+1}$ < $\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{x^n}$ = $\frac{1}{n-1}$.

Comment: 2) $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^n+x^2+1}$ < $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^2+1}$ = $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: 3) $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{x^2+1}-\frac{1}{x^n+x^2+1} dx$ = $\int_{0}^{1} \frac {x^n}{(x^2+1)(x^n+x^2+1)} dx$ < $\int_{0}^{1} x^n dx$ = $\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: 3) implies $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{x^n+x^2+1}$ > $\frac{\pi}{4}$ - $\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: That would be reasonable to put in as an actual answer, I think.  It does, in fact, answer one of the several questions you had (and you're allowed to answer yourself; even accept your own answer).  I thought you had done something like that, but utterly failed to think of splitting the interval at 1.

Comment: @Peter  Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the unanswered tab